# delete dynamically allocated memory in openGL

Tags: c++, glut

I use C++ and and freeglut, and want to know how to delete the dynamically allocated memory using `new`. I need to free the memory when closing the window. Where should I put this `delete pointer`?  before `glutMainLoop()`?

****Update****.

For example, I use `int *ptr = new int[n]` to store the vertex coordinates, and did not use class in the code. So I have to call `delete` in the `main()` to free the memory. I understand that I can use vector to do the same thing. But in my case, if I have to use `new`, how can I deallocate the memory?

Comment: How do delete _what_ allocated memory? What pointer are you trying to delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old form of GLUT made it so that your program's execution never returned from the call to `glutMainLoop`. FreeGLUT gets rid of this, but only if you specifically ask for it before calling `glutMainLoop`:

```
glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);
```

This means that, when you eventually call `glutLeaveMainLoop`, FreeGLUT will continue from where `glutMainLoop` was called, just like a regular function call.

So if you allocate memory before `glutMainLoop`, you can delete that memory afterwards.

That being said:

> I use int `*ptr = new int[n]` to store the vertex coordinates

Why isn't that a `std::vector<int> mem(n);` instead of a pointer? You can still get a pointer to the memory by doing `&mem[0]`. And it will clean up after itself.

Comment: Nicol, I don't think your last idea will work. The std::vector will be on the stack of the main() function. If gluMainLoop kills the app by calling exit() any variables allocated on the stack will be leaked. The vector will only get deallocted on its own if you use the GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION mode in freeglut to make the main() function return gracefully.

Comment: @Miguel: True, but since you're exiting the process, it doesn't matter. The OS will deallocate your process's memory. If cleaning up this memory actually is going to matter on some level, then the only way it will matter is if code is going to be executed after `glutMainLoop`. It's like running a program in the debugger and halting it instead of letting it run its course. It will be taken care of in due time.

Comment: I know, but I thought I should point that out though. The original question is about correctness, he wants to delete the memory he allocated, and I think that is a good principle. But I agree that there isn't really a technical reason to do that in this case.

Comment: @Nicol: do you mean if I close the window, the program will return from `glutMainLoop`? Then the program will continue executing the code after `glutMainLoop`?

Comment: @Nicol: I found the answer, it will continue implementing the code. right?  If I use vector, is there any problem? Where can I find the detailed documentation. The freeglut API document did not state anything about glutSetOption

Answer (score 2):

See question 3.0.70 in the [OpenGL GLUT FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/glut.htm). Short answer is use an exit handler installed via the atexit() call.

Comment: That faq is very old, and he's using FreeGLUT, which can return control to `main`. He should do that if he needs to, but I want clarification about what he's talking about before suggesting it.

Comment: I didn't know freeglut deviates from the original GLUT on this respect, thanks for pointing that out. But I don't think the FAQ is outdated. The original GLUT has this limitation on exit, so unless you are 100% sure you will never want to port your app to the original GLUT it would be good practice to adhere to the original GLUT API, even when using freeglut.

Comment: The original GLUT has not been updated in 10+ years. I'm not sure of a compelling reason for someone to limit oneself to that when FreeGLUT is just as widely supported (if not moreso), and provides additional, useful features.

Comment: I confirmed that the version of GLUT that ships with OS X adheres to the original API. So if you ever plan to distribute an app for that OS and want to avoid having to ship a custom framework I think restricting yourself to the original API is a good idea.

Comment: GLUT is not OpenGL. It is not something that "the system" provides. Or at least, you shouldn't be *relying* on the system-provided GLUT. If you're distributing an application that was written with FreeGLUT, you should be distributing FreeGLUT as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use smart pointers and you won't need to worry about it.

Comment: OSG has `osg::ref_ptr` otherwise you can use boost or smart pointers from new C++ standard.

Comment: Nice circumvention, but nothing else.